# SecPKCS12Import any time return empty items

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is my code. Any time items return is null.I have tried in `swift` and `objective c`,but nothing.

```
let certName : String = "private_key"//name of the certificate//
                    //get p12 file path
let resourcePath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(certName, ofType: "p12")!
let p12Data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)!
                    //create key dictionary for reading p12 file
let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
let options : NSDictionary = [key : "password"]
                    //create variable for holding security information
var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

var items : CFArray?

let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &items)
print(items)
```

Comment: What error does it return? You capture the error in `securityError`, but then ignore it.

Comment: securityError is equal 0,but items always returns nil

Comment: @ArthurSahakyan did you get answer, why items are nil ?

Comment: No but I have found other sloution,but in objective C

Comment: What was it ? Can you share your finding ? 
As i am having a same issue.

Comment: I am also having this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    I'm using pkcs8.    And you need to include 
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
openssl download from Github




    + (NSString*) getSignatureData:(NSString*) signableData  {
            // get private key path
            NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"private"
                                                             ofType:@"der"];

        NSData* datasss = [signableData dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];    
        char* text = (char*) [signableData UTF8String];
            unsigned char *data;
            data = (unsigned char *) text;

            //creates a new file BIO with mode, mode the meaning of mode is the same as the stdio function fopen()
            BIO *in = BIO_new_file([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "rb");

            //PKCS#8 private key info structure
            PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8inf = d2i_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO_bio(in, NULL);


            EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKCS82PKEY(p8inf);
            PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO_free(p8inf);
            BIO_free(in);

            uint8_t * cipherBuffer = NULL;

            // Calculate the buffer sizes.
            unsigned int cipherBufferSize = RSA_size(pkey->pkey.rsa);
            unsigned int signatureLength;

            // Allocate some buffer space.
            cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
            memset((void *)cipherBuffer, 0x0, cipherBufferSize);
            unsigned char hashedChars[32];
            //return a pointer to the hash value
            unsigned char *openSSLHash = CC_SHA256(datasss.bytes, (CC_LONG)signableData.length, hashedChars);
            //unsigned char *openSSLHash1 = SHA256(data, signableData.length, NULL);
            /*
             * The following function sign and verify a X509_SIG ASN1 object inside
             * PKCS#8 padded RSA encryption
             */
            RSA_sign(NID_sha256, openSSLHash, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH, cipherBuffer, &signatureLength, pkey->pkey.rsa);

            NSData *signedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void*)cipherBuffer length:signatureLength];

            EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
            NSString *base64String = [signedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


            return base64String;


        }
```